# Checking if the post's title is unique else return error - using friendly_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I have been trying to firstly check if the post's title is unique before posting it. In the model I added this line but it does not do what I expected:

```
validates_presence_of :title, uniqueness: true
```

Of course, I can check before making the post (in the controller) and if a post with this title exist to return an error message but is this the proper way to do it? I thought that there might be a validation for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should look like this

```
validates :title, presence: true, uniqueness: true
```

Comment: still the same. I get an article posted with title: testing and the second one: testing-f6daaf20-5cc4-41f6-9384-cf0410ced9a4

Comment: I got your problem, are you using friendly_id slug on this column?

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
validates :title, uniqueness: true
```

or

```
validates_uniqueness_of :title
```

Comment: still the same. I get an article posted with title: testing and the second one: testing-f6daaf20-5cc4-41f6-9384-cf0410ced9a4