# slug uniqueness and url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

i'm editing a website (not made by me) and I don't undestand one thing.

Short intro
When an user create a new product page, in `product.rb`, there is two `validates`

```
validates :title, presence: true
validates :slug, presence: true, uniqueness: true
```

The user can set only the `title` of the product and the `slug` (= the url) is generated automatically copying the title.
For example, if I set title: "Red", the page's url will be `mysite.com/products/red`

Now the question/problem

If I create a page with the same title of another page, the title will be always "Red" (because there is no uniqueness, obviously) but the slug (generated automatically) will be something like:

`mysite.com/products/red-af503270-0ffd-4654-b4e9-a210e6a6500e`

A very long url.

Why? I can't find the script that is making it.
Because I want to edit it to make the title progressive. For example `mysite.com/products//red-2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this because the creator of web using [friendly_id Gem](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id), and the very long url is to make sure Uniqueness

When you try to insert a record that would generate a duplicate friendly id, FriendlyId will append a UUID to the generated slug to ensure uniqueness:

```
car = Car.create :title => "Peugeot 206"
car2 = Car.create :title => "Peugeot 206"

car.friendly_id #=> "peugeot-206"
car2.friendly_id #=> "peugeot-206-f9f3789a-daec-4156-af1d-fab81aa16ee5"
```

you can learn more to custom it [from this link](https://norman.github.io/friendly_id/file.Guide.html)

Comment: oh, you have right. Just found   `extend FriendlyId` and  `friendly_id :title, use: [:slugged, :finders]` in the product.rb. Do you know how to make it shorter?

Comment: this answer has detail explanation if you want to change it , https://stackoverflow.com/a/25380607/938947